# Delete Rows older than X days - Linq Mongo

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to delete rows older than 3 days from MongoDB. My date in MongoDB ios stored as `ISODate("2014-02-03T16:21:13.267Z")`.

I generated Query as follows:

```
DateTime timeStamp = DateTime.Now.Date;
DateTime dateDiff = timeStamp.AddDays(-Days);

var qrySelectedDates = Query.And(
                        Query.GTE("InsertTime", dateDiff),
                        Query.LTE("InsertTime", dateDiff.Add(new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59))));

Coll.Remove(qrySelectedDates);
```

What mistake am I making here. Can anyone please suggest me.
Thank You in advance

Comment: What problem are you having? An error? No documents removed?